# Jasmine mock chained methods with Karma and Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to mock `angular.element`. And I want to ensure `angular.element` has been called a certain amount of times and that `anguler.element.attr` has been called too.

I have the following code:

```
var things = $scope.getThings();

for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
  if (things[i].type == "xyz") {
    angular.element("#thing-" + things[i].id)
      .attr("foo", things[i].bar);
  };
};
```

In my test I have:

```
var things = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: "xyz",
    bar: 10
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "abc",
    bar: 33
  }
];

spyOn($rootScope, "getThings").and.returnValue(things);
spyOn(angular, "element").and.returnValue();

$rootScope.doThings(); // call controller method

expect(angular.element.calls.count()).toBe(1);
```

But it gives the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'angular.element("#thing-" + things[i].id).attr')

I also want my test to have something like:

```
expect(angular.element.attr.calls.count()).toBe(1);
expect(angular.element.attr).tohaveBeenCalledWith("foo", things[0].bar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way chained methods should be spied or mocked solely depends on how they are defined on the spied objects.

In the case of Angular jqLite, or in your case, jQuery (both are transparently served through `angular.element` facade) chained methods are defined on constructor prototype, which is exposed on factory function as `angular.element.prototype` or `jQuery.prototype` (`angular.element === jQuery` when jQuery is loaded).

In order to spy on both `angular.element` and `angular.element(...).attr` it should be:

```
spyOn(angular, 'element').and.callThrough();
spyOn(angular.element.prototype, 'attr').and.callThrough();
...
expect(angular.element).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(angular.element.prototype.attr).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

`callThrough` is important in this case because otherwise the whole chain should be stubbed manually.

Comment: Am I right that using `callThrough` means I need the jQuery library included for the test? Using `callThrough` means the unit test will actually use jQuery and if jQuery breaks then my unit test breaks?

Comment: @benjovanic You haven't specified that you need to keep jQuery out of the spec in your question. But yes, you need to include it. And no, it shouldn't break, the code above won't throw even if there are no elements for '"#thing-...' selector (there should DOM fixtures for potentially absent elements when jQuery code is tested, but it is not a problem here).

Answer (score 1):

try to add this code:

```
var spy;

beforeEach(function() {
    spy = spyOn(angular, 'element').....
});

afterEach(function() {
    spy.andCallThrough();
});
```

you can find more in: [Jasmin docs](http://tobyho.com/2011/12/15/jasmine-spy-cheatsheet/)