# Jasmine test for method containing jQuery

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following method in my controller:

```
$scope.onWindowResize = function() {
    var dWidth= $('#div1').width();
    var left = $('#div1').position().left;
    $('.myClass1').css({'width':dWdth});
    $('.myClass2').css({'left': left});
}
```

I am trying to test the method onWindowResize() with the below code.

```
it('onWindowResize()', inject(function () {
    scope.onWindowResize();
    scope.$apply();
}));
```

But I get this error message:

```
"message": "'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$('#div1').position().left')"
```

and

```
dWidth is null
```

I have sinon spy, but not sure how to use it here. Can I use it somehow to spy on it, or is there a better way to test this method? I think I need to mock "**$('#div1')**", but no idea how to do that. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasmine mock chained methods with Karma and Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285896/jasmine-mock-chained-methods-with-karma-and-angular)

Comment: Basically the entire `$('#div1').position().left` chain should be recreated as a stub.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is typo in your code, you're using `dWidth` wrong in css function like this `adjWdth`.
You can create a spy on `$` / `jQuery` function like this and spy for css function

```
var cssSpy = jasmine.createSpy('cssSpy');
$ = jasmine.createSpy().andCallFake(function(){
    return {
        width:function(){return 200;},
        position: function(){return{left:500};},
        css: cssSpy
    };
});
$scope.onWindowResize();
expect(cssSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({'width':200});
expect(cssSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({'left':500});
```

As you can see, I'm overwriting `$` / `jQuery` function itself and returning an object with the properties/methods you use in the `onWindowResize` function. And also a spy for css function. `andCallFake` is old version of jasmine the new one is `.and.callFake()`. Please confirm if it works for you and study it well. You can do it in `beforeEach` block to be reusable and mock all keys you want to return when you selecting a DOM element ;). **By the way, it's not recommended to have a DOM manipulation code inside controller, it should be in a directive's link function.**

Comment: what about your confirmation to my question buddy :D